# jsTree JSON parse issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jstree

I use JSTree plugin to display department stricture.
Serverside (asp.net 3.5) works well and I get JSON object.

But when I try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btntst').click(function () {
        $('#mainDiv').html('wait for data');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '_layouts/GridView/ApplicationPage1.aspx/getTable',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{}",
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#jsTreeContainer').jstree({
                    "json_data": {
                        "data": [msg.d]
                    }
                    , "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"]
                });
            }
            , timeout: 60000
        });
    });

});
```

I get only one node with all JSON string in it.
JSON-string, returned by webmethod is:

```
{
  'data': 'department001',
  'attr': {
    'id': 'nodeid1773'
  },
  'children': [

  ]
},
{
  'data': 'department001',
  'attr': {
    'id': 'nodeid1779'
  },
  'children': [

  ]
}
```

If I copy-paste this string to:

```
"json_data": {"data" : [...] }
```

I get correct result.
Pleas help, can't get what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is looking for a JSON object of type `json_data` but the normal response is only `data`. See if these changes work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btntst').click(function () {
        $('#mainDiv').html('wait for data');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '_layouts/GridView/ApplicationPage1.aspx/getTable',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{}",
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#jsTreeContainer').jstree({
                    "json_data": [msg.d],
                    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"]
                });
            }
            , timeout: 60000
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: i got error: uncaught exception: Neither data nor ajax settings supplied. in my firebug. But Your suggestion gave me right direction: "json_data": {"data": [JSON.parse(msg.d)]},